# how to add a button that overrides a storyboard segue (in swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue, uistoryboard

I added a storyboard segue to add text to a photo. Right now you would have to go through 3 view controllers to get the final photo. A(options menu) -> B(enter text) -> C(take photo). If I add a button to vc b it shows up as a sigabrt error. If I comment out the code below there is no error. Its obvious the issue is the storyboard segue. All i want to do is have a button that can go from b->a without a runtime error coming up. The code below is vc b. Just to let you know I can go from c ->a no problem but I want to go from b -> a

```
import UIKit

class customViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var zext: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   var destviewc: ccViewController = segue.destination as! ccViewController
    destviewc.labelText = zext.text!


} }
```

Comment: are you sure segue.destination can be cast to  ccViewController?? try to use segue.destination as? ccViewController and check if its nill or not?

Comment: @Mohammadalijf how do I check if ccViewController is nil or not? Thanks

Comment: you dont check ccViewController is nil or not. You check if casting segue.destination to ccViewController is resulting nil or not. Like how ryan said you can use guard statement to control if a variable is nil or not. Also you can use 'if let'. E.g 'if let desViewC = segue.destination as? ccViewControll { do stuff with desViewC } else { desCieeC is nill you can do sth about it here }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of `prepare(for:sender:)` is making runtime assumptions about the presence of certain values (using `!`). Namely, that `segue.destination` is a `ccViewController` and `zext.text` is not nil. If these assumptions are incorrect you will experience a runtime error.

Instead you can employ some defensive techniques using the Swift `guard` statements to ensure your method is in the right state to continue execution.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let destViewC = segue.destination as? CCViewController else {
        return
    }

    guard let text = zext.text else {
        return
    }

    destViewC.labelText = text
}
```

Also, type names should use upper camel case. That is, "customViewController" should be "CustomViewController".